# pyjnius library installation program execution error

Tags: python, java-7, pyjnius

I am trying to install pyjnius, & when i execute simple program it shows following error..
 How do i solve it?

```
 SystemError: Error calling dlopen(/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64      /server/libjvm.so: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/lib/amd6h file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Pyjnius depends on Cython and Java. Assuming that you already have Java installed. Please do the following:

```
su
pip install cython
pip install pyjnius
```

## Example

[image]